# Getting error as the name Session does not exist for Sessions in ASP.NET Core 8.0

Tags: asp.net-core

I am working on a ECom project, and I am stuck at a place where I am creating a partial method in a controller for `CartSession`. I am getting an error for session that says

> The name session does not exist in the current context.

I have tried multiple approaches from online but none of them working. Below is my VM class for `Cart` and followed by controller method.

View model class:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string? NamePrd { get; set; }
public int? Quantity { get; set; }
public decimal? Price { get; set; }
public decimal? Total { get { return Quantity * Price; } }
public string? PrdImage { get; set; }
```

Controller action method

```
public IActionResult CartPartial()
{
    // Init CartVM
    CartVM model = new CartVM();

    // Init quantity
    int qty = 0;

    // Init Price
    decimal price = 0;

    // Check for cart session
    if (Session["cart"] != null)
    {
        var list = (List<CartVM>)Session["cart"];

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            // Get total qty and price
            qty += item.Quantity;
            price += item.Price;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Or set total qty and price to 0
        model.Quantity = 0;
        model.Price = 0m;
    }

    // Return partial view with model
    return View(model);
}
```

I am using ASP.NET Core 8.0 framework.

Comment: Have you read the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-8.0 ? A controller doesn’t have a property called `Session` by itself as the error says. You probably want to look into `HttpContext`

Comment: Do you want to get cart in CartPartial ? Where do you set the cart ?

Comment: I want to CartParial in the Top menu right size

Comment: @QingGuo I want to include CartPartial in the TopMenu header section

Comment: How do you create your cart object ?

Comment: I have created a model class by the name CartVM, above I have added the properties listed in the VM object. And then I am creating a Partial View in Controller which I will use it in TopMenu

Comment: Yes, it looks loke that, the problem is Session["cart"] not work , you need another way to pass the cart to the CartPartial() action so that you can set model value.